# get_headers Connection time out

Tags: php, timeout, get-headers

I get this error message: `get_headers failed to open stream: Connection timeout`

Here is the code:

```
$file_headers = @get_headers('http://www.example.fr');
print_r(get_headers('http://www.example.fr'));

if ( strpos( $file_headers[0], "200" )) {
    echo 'done';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this for 120 sec timeout (default - 60):

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
```

Answer (score 0):

The program was not able to open the stream within the time limit -- a system default value, often 60 seconds.  Check to see that the file exists and is readable.  Note that you call **get_headers** a second time (in the **print** statement), while the **file_headers** stream is still active.

Comment: i didn't understand clearly can you explain me thank you

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: this sentence  Note that you call get_headers a second time (in the print statement), while the file_headers stream is still active.

Comment: You invoke **get_headers** once to set up **file_headers**  I believe that this opens the stream.  In the next statement, the **print_r**, you call **get_headers** again.  I believe that the error message is telling you that it couldn't open the file a second time.